# Aes data encryption in one android device and decryption in another device

Tags: android, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt my data with 128 bit my own key and decrypt in another device using the same key. I saw several libraries which generates key automatically. But i need to use my own key for encryption and decryption. Is anyone tell me how to do this with an example. Thanks in advance

Comment: A key is simply a `byte[]` and most libraries permit you to use one yourself. Can you give an example where this is not the case aside from password-based encryption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer for my question for aes encryption there is a simple cross platform library. Please go to the below link

[Cross platform library for aes encryption](https://github.com/Pakhee/Cross-platform-AES-encryption)